# Jquery fadeIn fadeOut on click (data attr)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following set up in my html:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
                    <img id="click-1" class="glasses one active" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/images/Statesman-Three.png"/>
                    <img id="click-2" class="glasses two" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/images/Statesman-Three.png" style="background:red;"/>
                    <img id="click-3" class="glasses three" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/images/Statesman-Three.png" style="background:blue;"/>
                    <img id="click-4" class="glasses four" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/images/Statesman-Three.png" style="background:pink;"/>
                    <ul class="toggle_points">
                        <li data-toggle-target="click-1">
                            <div class="circle"><div class="inner_circle"></div></div>
                        </li>
                        <li data-toggle-target="click-2">
                            <div class="circle"><div class="inner_circle"></div></div>
                        </li>
                        <li data-toggle-target="click-3">
                            <div class="circle"><div class="inner_circle"></div></div>
                        </li>
                        <li data-toggle-target="click-4">
                            <div class="circle"><div class="inner_circle"></div></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

And I'm looking to fadein and out images based on the click.  I have them sharing a connect with a data-attr and Id's.

I feel like my current jquery is on the right path but Im definitely missing/forgetting something

```
$('.toggle_points li').click(function (e) {
          $( '#' + $(this).data('toggleTarget') ).fadeIn().toggleClass('active').find('img.active').fadeOut().removeClass('active);
        });
```

Comment: did you notice the typo? It should be: `.removeClass('active')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break up your jQuery statement into:

```
$('.toggle_points li').click(function (e) {
    $('img.glasses.active').fadeOut().removeClass('active');
    $( '#' + $(this).data('toggleTarget') ).fadeIn().toggleClass('active');
});
```

In your code, `.find('img.active')` will attempt to search the descendants of the image you select, but won't find a match since the image you want isn't a descendant. Also, you left out a `'` in your removeClass().

Comment: In your code you add class active and then remove, because `$('img.glasses.active')` will be matched

Comment: @marsh - Good catch. The lines needed to be swapped.

Comment: @j08691, is it possible to also add and remove a class if the li is the current one?

Comment: @RMH - do you mean if someone clicks on the already active/current list item?

Comment: yes, so after this runs the image is active and its data-attr list item would also be technically

Comment: I'm just unclear as what you want to happen. If I click a div, and the corresponding image is shown and given the active class, what do you want to happen if the same div is clicked again?

Comment: it would remain active.  Its almost like the list items are the tabs.  The current one that has its attribute clicked would be the current one alone with the current image. Does that make sense? If not its ok, I appreciate the help either way!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72703/discussion-between-rmh-and-j08691).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k53k9ydy/ that should lead you in the right direction and also caches the elements you're selecting to variables.

```
$('.toggle_points li').on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var el = $(this).data('toggleTarget');
    if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
        $('#' + el).fadeIn().toggleClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#' + el).fadeOut().toggleClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```